# Traverse const array in random order

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to…

```
std::random_shuffle(begin(a), end(a));
for (auto x : a) {
  use(x);
}
```

…but `a` is `const`. Is a random-order traversal possible in O(*n*) time and O(1) space?

Comment: I've closed this question as a duplicate of a previous question. Whether or not it's constant memory depends on your model of computation.

Comment: Thanks @orlp. That fits the bill perfectly.